# Writing file with batch but text is disappearing

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, vbscript, echo

I have a problem with writing a file with a batch file. 
It seems that one character is triggering the echo end like this one: 
the code is a downloader.

```
C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO if WScript.Arguments.Count < 1 then
```

But the file output is this.

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count  then
```

Here's my code:

```
mkdir C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder


>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO if WScript.Arguments.Count <1 then
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO   MsgBox "Usage: wget.vbs <url> (file)"
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO   WScript.Quit
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO end if
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO URL = WScript.Arguments(0)
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO if WScript.Arguments.Count > 1 then
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO   saveTo = WScript.Arguments(1)
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO else
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO   parts = split(url,"/") 
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO   saveTo = parts(ubound(parts))
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO end if
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO objXMLHTTP.open "GET", URL, false
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO objXMLHTTP.send()
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO objADOStream.Open
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO If objFSO.Fileexists(saveTo) Then objFSO.DeleteFile saveTo
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO Set objFSO = Nothing
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO objADOStream.SaveToFile saveTo
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO objADOStream.Close
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO Set objADOStream = Nothing
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO End if
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO WScript.Quit
start C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs (link goes here )
```

And the whole echo output is this

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count  then      <---- some numbers are missing 
MsgBox "Usage: wget.vbs <url> (file)"
WScript.Quit
end if
URL = WScript.Arguments(0)              <------- 1 line is missing 
saveTo = WScript.Arguments(1)
else
parts = split(url,"/") 
saveTo = parts(ubound(parts))
end if
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", URL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(saveTo) Then objFSO.DeleteFile saveTo
Set objFSO = Nothing
objADOStream.SaveToFile saveTo
objADOStream.Close
Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

As you can see, there's one line missing from the echo'd text.
Is there some kind of start and end character so I could echo commands like those?

I would be happy if somebody could answer my question.

Comment: You are writing a batch file that is writing a vbs file. Just write the VBS file and run it.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the > or < characters, like so: ^> or ^< (For the parts that go into the vbs script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO if WScript.Arguments.Count <1 then` as the example....

If you try this specific line by itself form a command prompt, it will fail with a "The system cannot find the file specified" error.

This is because it's reading the `<1` as a file input command (opposite of the output `>`).

So you'd have to 'escape' the `<` so that it gets treated like a plain text character in the Echo, and not as a file input redirect command.

Meaning, for this case, you'd want to use:

```
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO if WScript.Arguments.Count ^<1 then
```

Same with

```
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO if WScript.Arguments.Count > 1 then
```

You'd want to escape the `>` in that one:

```
>> C:\ProgramData\Tempfolder\test.vbs ECHO if WScript.Arguments.Count ^> 1 then
```

The `^` is the batch escape character, and you'll want to keep this in mind for each line you're echoing out, in case it's needed.

From http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html:

> ^  Escape character.
>
> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be
>   treated as ordinary text.   When piping or redirecting any of these
>   charcters you should prefix with the escape character: & \ < > ^ |
>
> ```
>  e.g.  ^\  ^&  ^|  ^>  ^<  ^^
> ```